# copy paste loop to 1 colomn 1 colomn

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUAwA.png)

```
Sub Macro2()
Range("D3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B9").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

how code vba excel for copy paste 1 colomn 1 colomn (not copy area) with COUNTA.
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBwXCg6wbPEgV7qdMicH8ZqAGkxoExnpRSGpa5SOaKY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line

```
Sub Test()
Range("B2").Resize(Range("D2").Value).Value = Range("D3").Value
End Sub
```

Or do you mean something like that

```
Sub Test()
Range("B8").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Resize(Range("D2").Value).Value = Range("D3").Value
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: oke thanks, how use code Offset(1, 0).Select in code. for copy and cut to table select

Comment: Why do you want to use offset ..? What is your final desired output?

Comment: Sub Test()
    Range("B8").select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).select
    loop
    Resize(Range("D2").Value).Value = Range("D3").Value,1).copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub

i will try error, you can help

Comment: I can't get exactly what you want to do .. I have edited the post but if this is not the desired please post before and after snapshots

Comment: yes i try, how make use code offset loop in code that ?

Comment: im click posting move left to right ilustration in image in link that 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WYi-3bjozKbtcqG1VH194gy6QBbSQEbBDsg51gMmCEM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: YasserKhalil how clear content / delete with vba excel 
i view ilustration data in google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBwXCg6wbPEgV7qdMicH8ZqAGkxoExnpRSGpa5SOaKY/edit#gid=324981252

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435062/delete-clear-content-with-vba-excel-count